Import DNS record created by Python script on Terraform created infra
My terraform configuration sets up AWS infra for a web app, including the common services required. After the terraform setup finishes, Jenkins runs a Python script that updates name servers on Porkbun to point to AWS name servers. In addition, during Terraform setup, an ACM certificate is generated. The python script adds a CNAME record with the challenge given by the ACM cert to the application hosted zone records.
The issue is when I do terraform destroy, because the Python code added a CNAME record, Terraform is unable to destroy the zone, because an entry generated there isn't managed by Terraform.
I am trying to understand if my method is wrong, or if there's an appropriate solution to this. I imagine the ''shortest'' way would be to import into terraform the changes done by the script?
Of course when I manually delete the CNAME entry, Terraform is able to destroy all resources it has created. Ideally, I'd want the import into terraform function to happen dynamically in the same script.
dns.tf configuration is as follows:
resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = var.domain_name
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = "www.${var.domain_name}"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [aws_instance.resume-app-ec2-instance.public_ip]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "root" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = var.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [aws_instance.resume-app-ec2-instance.public_ip]
}

This is the custom Python script I'm running that dynamically fetches the name servers created by Terraform for the specific hosted zone, and updates Porkbun name servers via API. Then it gets the ACM certificate challenge that's also configred via Terraform, and creates a CNAME record for the domain.
import requests
import json
import boto3
import time

print("Firing up domain changes...")
time.sleep(3)

# AWS Secret Manager details
secret_name = "aws-pork-dns-ns"
region_name = "us-east-1"

# Porkbun Domain Name
domain_name = "redacted :)"

# Initialize a Secrets Manager client
client = boto3.client('secretsmanager', region_name=region_name)

# Retrieve Porkbun API credentials from AWS Secret Manager
response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
secret_dict = json.loads(response['SecretString'])
pork_api_key = secret_dict['pork_api_key']
pork_api_secret = secret_dict['pork_api_secret']

# Retrieve name servers from Route 53
route53_client = boto3.client('route53')
response = route53_client.list_hosted_zones_by_name(DNSName=domain_name)
hosted_zone_id = response['HostedZones'][0]['Id'].split('/')[-1]
response = route53_client.get_hosted_zone(Id=hosted_zone_id)
name_servers = response['DelegationSet']['NameServers']

# Construct the request body to update name servers according to the Porkbun API documentation
request_body = {
    "apikey": pork_api_key,
    "secretapikey": pork_api_secret,
    "ns": name_servers
}

# Update name servers on Porkbun
url = f"https://porkbun.com/api/json/v3/domain/updateNs/{domain_name}"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=request_body)

# Check the response for name server update
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Name servers updated successfully.")
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("Failed to update name servers.")
    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.json())

# Wait for a few seconds for DNS propagation
print("Hold on, waiting for records to propagate before continuing...")
time.sleep(30)

# Get ACM certificate ARN
acm_client = boto3.client('acm')
response = acm_client.list_certificates()
certificate_arn = None
for certificate in response['CertificateSummaryList']:
    if certificate['DomainName'] == domain_name:
        certificate_arn = certificate['CertificateArn']
        break

if certificate_arn:
    # Get DNS validation options
    response = acm_client.describe_certificate(CertificateArn=certificate_arn)
    validation_options = response['Certificate']['DomainValidationOptions']
    for option in validation_options:
        if option['ValidationMethod'] == 'DNS':
            dns_record_name = option['ResourceRecord']['Name']
            dns_record_value = option['ResourceRecord']['Value']

            # Create CNAME record in Route 53
            response = route53_client.change_resource_record_sets(
                HostedZoneId=hosted_zone_id,
                ChangeBatch={
                    'Changes': [{
                        'Action': 'UPSERT',
                        'ResourceRecordSet': {
                            'Name': dns_record_name,
                            'Type': 'CNAME',
                            'TTL': 300,
                            'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': dns_record_value}]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            )

            print("CNAME record created successfully.")
            print("DNS Record Name:", dns_record_name)
            print("DNS Record Value:", dns_record_value)
            break
else:
    print("ACM certificate not found for domain:", domain_name)


acm.tf is as follows:
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "resume-app-cert" {
  domain_name       = var.domain_name
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags = {
    Name = "resume-app-ssl-cert"
  }
}



Could you perhaps share with us some of your code and configurations? And as you said, importing them is perhaps the best idea. Starting from Terraform v1.5.0, import is supported. I don't know if you are using raw resource for the records or not. But let's say that's the case: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record#import. You might need to write some custom logic to query the AWS APIs to fetch the records and then via some templating, write it to .tf files and then run them. But until more information is provided, I can't say more.

Thank you @Algo7, I have added what I think is most relevant. I am happy to add more if you want to have more visibility.

@Assaf I don't see where in your terraform code is the CNAME record created, there are only two A records.

@MarkoE Thanks for replying. The CNAME record isn't created by Terraform currently, the Python script fetches the ACM challenge, and creates a CNAME record. I did this mainly because I need this setup to be from 0 to 100 in a single pipeline build command. But of course I might be wrong in the methodology. I have tried to perhaps create an empty CNAME record with Terraform, and then have the Python script add an entry, but that didn't work out too well so far.

Ok, and why do you want to destroy the record now?

@MarkoE I just thought that it's best practice to make sure Terraform has the ability to fully manage the infrastructure. Also my OCD maybe.

And importing the record into terraform didn't work?

@markoE, I’m trying to understand how to implement this into my methodology. The terraform infra is part of a Jenkins pipeline, which builds a docker image, sets up Terraform infra, deploys the container in EC2, then runs the Python script. What are your thoughts?

I actually don't understand what the problem is. :) I can only say that I would steer clear of using the combination where a part of infrastructure is created using IaC, and another part without using IaC.

@MarkoE, thanks. Let me ask you this question: Terraform sets up ACM and Hosted Zone for my domain. How can I have Terraform create within my Hosted Zone, an appropriate CNAME record, that it's value is the value generated by the ACM challenge? This needs to be from 0 to 100, so I can't hard code the challenge into my Terraform code. I couldn't figure this out without using an external script that fetches the challenge generated by the ACM, and inputs a CNAME record. Thank you Marko.

There is a way to automatically validate your ACM certificate: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation.

@MarkoE Thank you Marko, I will test this and update here when I get to it. Appreciate your responses here.

@MarkoE Marko.... no words brother, this has worked. Thank you so so much. I learned so much from troubleshooting this, and it's nice to finally solve this issue.

Yup, things are usually much simpler than they look. Glad it worked!

This might not be the best practice, as other have pointed out the best practice is to manage everything by terraform
But if you just need an easy way out. This should work as a solution
By adding force_destroy = true to your hosted_zone
resource "aws_route53_zone" "private" {
  name          = "example.com"
  force_destroy = true
}

